# webpack unable to resolve node module in docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, yarnpkg

```
#Dockerfile

FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir /morty
ADD . /morty/
WORKDIR /morty/
RUN yarn cache clean && yarn install
RUN ls node_modules | grep autosuggest
RUN find /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest -ls

CMD npm run dev
```

This builds as expected, but as soon as I request a page from the dev server, I get an error

```
ERROR in ./src/components/molecules/AutoSuggest/index.js
web_1         | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-autosuggest' in '/morty/src/components/molecules/AutoSuggest'
web_1         |  @
```

which would suggest to me that for some reason, the `react-autosuggest` module was not installed; however, the output of step 6 & 7 in my `Dockerfile` seems to invalidate that hypothesis.

```
Step 6/7 : RUN ls node_modules | grep autosuggest
 ---> Running in 0c87c4318a6f
react-autosuggest

Step 7/9 : RUN find /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest -ls
 ---> Running in 498c6b9080c7
12042711    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest
12042729    4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         4096 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist
521128    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1735 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/theme.js
12042731    4 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         4096 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/standalone
521127   36 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        33193 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/standalone/autosuggest.min.js
521126  112 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       113248 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/standalone/autosuggest.js
521123   28 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        27217 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/Autosuggest.js
521124    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root           65 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/dist/index.js
521121   24 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        24423 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/README.md
521129    8 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         4195 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/package.json
521120    4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1088 Mar  6 16:40 /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest/LICENSE
```

`package.json` does contain the entry `"react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",` in `dependencies` and the app performs as expected in its un-containerized form.

also, possibly relevant is that the base config for this project came from 
[the Arc project](https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/wiki/Webpack)

Comment: Have you tried locally outside the docker image?

Comment: "and the app performs as expected in its un-containerized form."

Comment: A `RUN find /morty/node_modules/react-autosuggest -ls` output would also be useful.  Do you have similar node versions inside and outside the container?
 Can you try running the same image with a named volume `docker run -v morty:/morty`?

Comment: output of `find` added above

Comment: @Ben did you ever fix this? having a similar issue

Comment: @Matt why would a different node version outside of the container make a difference?

Comment: @thanatorr I've seen projects bork when you mount the local systems `node_modules` into a container. Usually when you jump npm/yarn versions, or go from osx/windows to docker.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue while trying to build my npm project using a container which had `WORKDIR` as a mounted volume. I resolved this issue by removing the mounted volume by name.

`docker volume ls` to list the volumes

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               myproject_named_volume
```

`docker volume rm -f myproject_named_volume` to remove the volume

Hope this helps.